# loop in Matlab/Simulink HDL

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, hdl-coder

In attached picture a model is given with `3` inputs and `3` outputs.
I would like to run this model `10` times in loop. Kindly does any one know how I can use outputs as inputs from second run till `10`th run please help me. I would like to use my outputs (1 to 3) as inputs from from second till 10th iterations.

First run: `3` inputs are `10`, `24` and `21`,
Second run till `10th`: out1 to be used for place of first `input(10)`, `out2`to be used for second `input(24)` and `out3` to be used for third `input(21)`
Thanks alot

[image]

Comment: I copied the image while searching for solution ,facing similar kind of issue. Any idea please?

Comment: I wrote an answer to the other question, did you read and understand it? I don't see where your issue is different to the other question.

Comment: The link you wrote I have this example but unable to understand it. Could you explain it bit more please

Comment: If you don't understand my answer, please ask specific questions commenting the answer.